# VS Code Python can't recognise pip installed modules

Tags: python, module

I've imported pyttsx3 and PySimpleGUI and they worked fine just days ago, now with a VS Code update they aren't recognised. I've reinstalled them and that still didn't fix it.

```
import pyttsx3
import PySimpleGUI
```

Comment: Have you checked that you are using the correct python interpreter (especially if you have several virtual environments)?

Comment: @FlorentMonin Not sure, it popped up telling me to select one and I just selected the one it recommended me to use

Comment: Make sure you have the correct interpreter selected (there can be more than one installed) and that interpreter match the pip you used for installing the package.
On mac, you can switch the interpreter using <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>. To check if the `pip` executable you used matches the interpreter, go to the terminal and type `which pip` and note the path. Pick the python interpreter in the same directory as it.

Comment: Ohh just realised i had misclicked and selected the global instead of recommended

Answer (score 0):

Set interpreter to the recommended after misclick

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).